# Is there a version of Sharepoint that many users could access from their home computers?

Tags: web-services

I need to build a SharePoint site that many users can access from their home computers or mobile devices. I am fairly new to SharePoint so I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting from scratch then probably the easiest route to persue would be the SharePoint Online option (http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint/sharepoint-online-online-collaboration-software-FX103789366.aspx).

Being cloud-based it is accessible anywhere you have an internet connection and the latest version of SharePoint allows for reasonably straightforward multi-device rendering.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Fairfield said, the other way of doing this would basically involve creating a company extranet site and then using forms based authentication. This is not a trivial task, so you may find it better to use SP Online.